# Не могу получить данные с url используя Retrofit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, recyclerview, retrofit

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var recyclerAdapter: Adapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        recyclerView = recyclerViewNews
        recyclerAdapter = Adapter(this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter


      val apiService = ApiService.create().getNews()
        apiService.enqueue(object : Callback<List<News>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<News>>, response: Response<List<News>>?) {
                val body = response?.body()
                if(body != null){
                    recyclerAdapter.setNewsListItems(body)
                }
                    Log.v("checkResponseProfile",response!!.body().toString()+"code"+response.code())

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<News>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("Error", "Error")
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Модель класса

```
data class News(
    var title: String,
    var type: String,
    var img: String,
    var clickUrl: String,
    var time: String,
    var top: String
)
```

Интерфейс ApiService

```
interface ApiService {
    @GET("news_array.json")
    fun getNews(): Call<List<News>>

    companion object {
        var BASE_URL = "http://188.40.167.45:3001"
        fun create(): ApiService {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()
            return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Адаптер

```
class Adapter(val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {
    var newsList:List<News> = listOf()


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_news, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = newsList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val news = newsList[position]

        holder.titleTextView.text = news.title
        holder.sourceTextView.text = news.clickUrl
        holder.timeTextView.text = news.time
    }


    fun setNewsListItems(newsList: List<News>){
        this.newsList = newsList;
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val titleTextView: TextView = itemView.tvTitle
        val sourceTextView: TextView = itemView.tvSource
        val timeTextView: TextView = itemView.tvTime

    }

}
```

В логе всплывает проверка onResponse, но видимо responce.body() = null

V/checkResponseProfile: nullcode404

Comment: поменял, без изменений, адрес корректный, проверял на postman

Comment: А с дебаггером работать умеете? По хорошему, тут бы точку останова на `if(body != null)` и посмотреть, что внутри

Comment: В общем получилось, увидел в дебаггере, что у меня http://188.40.167.45:3001.news_array.json, а мне ведь просто нужна ссылка http://188.40.167.45:3001, так что я в интерфейсе в @GET ничего не поставил, то есть " ", и получил данные)